# Unnecessary lines appearing between image-links

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, image

I'm using three images side-by-side, and adding a Url.Action to each one of them.  The code works fine, but the images are being displayed w/ some sort of line between them.  Here is my code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Subcribe", new { id = item.ID })">
    <img src="images\subscribe.png" style="border:0" alt="Subscribe" />
</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.ID })">
    <img src="images\edit.png" style="border:0" alt="Edit" />
</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.ID })">
    <img src="images\delete.png" style="border:0" alt="Delete" />
</a>
```

Edit - This is also happening when I tried an alternate, non-Url.Action method:

```
<a href="Subcribe\@item.ID">
    <img src="images\subscribe.png" style="border:0" alt="Subscribe" />
</a>
```

Here is how the images are displaying:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Presumably you've tried `outline: none; text-decoration: none;`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried text-decoration and border-style, in addition to border:0.  I hadn't tried outline, but the answer below worked (removing the line-breaks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put each image in one line:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Subcribe", new { id = item.ID })"><img src="images\subscribe.png" style="border:0" alt="Subscribe" /></a>
```

It seems to be the underline of an space in your link. You can also add 'text-decoration: none;' in the style of those links.

Comment: Wow, thanks @morgar.  I've been trying all sorts of style changes (text-decoration, border-style, etc), but nothing has worked.  Your extremely simple solution worked.  Thanks again.

Comment: That's great. The problem is browsers convert carriage returns to spaces, so they were added to your links.